# Creating a bash script that logs the output of 'watch lsusb' into an empty file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, watch, lsusb

I have an embedded Linux system (running Ubuntu 10) on a microprocessor that has an onboard USB hub (specifically a BeagleBone Black).

I made a simple bash script that's supposed to run a command, `watch lsusb`; and as that runs, my program needs to dump the output my command generates into a text or JSON file (ideally on a USB stick, called `usb0` for the sake of the example).

So far, this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
#DATE=$(date +'%F %H:%M:%S')
DIR=/home/ubuntu/lsusb_logs
CMD='watch lsusb'
$CMD > $DIR
```

This runs until I stop it, which is fine. But when I go to look at my now created `lsusb_logs` file, all the data appears to be either encoded or needs to be formatted because its not at all like the original format a single `lsusb` or even `watch lsusb` outputs.

The purpose of this script is to gather historical data of the peripherals on the USB hub state over a 24 hour period in an environment chamber (climate stress testing).

Any advice or insight is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`watch` is going to print some non-readable characters because it needs to clear the screen every time it runs the command. You could however just run the command in an infinite while loop with some delay:

```
while true; do
    lsusb >> lsusb_logs
    sleep 1 # 1 second delay
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the same repetitive command indefinitely, you can take another approach.

You can utilize `udev` to monitor for `plugged` or `unplugged` USB devices, and execute a script at that time.

Example, create 2 scripts:

```
vi /bin/device_added.sh
vi /bin/device_removed.sh
```

which will log to a log file the ACTION (added or removed),

and make those executable:

```
chmod +x /bin/device_added.sh
chmod +x /bin/device_removed.sh
```

then create a udev rule that will contain the triggers on when a device change is detected:

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/80-test.rules
```

which will contain for example:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",  RUN+="/bin/device_added.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_removed.sh"
```

This way with your 2 scripts log only upon change, and not all the time..